# Jacobian of vec of a matrix into vec of its inverse

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, jacobian

Suppose that $X$ is invertible and $n\times n$ and the transformation:
$$
\varphi:\operatorname{vec}(X)\mapsto\operatorname{vec}(X^{-1}).
$$
For example, with $n=2$ and $X=\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ c &d\end{pmatrix}$, we have
$$
\varphi:\begin{pmatrix}a \\ c \\ b \\ d\end{pmatrix}\mapsto\frac{1}{ad-bc}\begin{pmatrix}d \\ -c \\ -b \\ a\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Can you point me to some references (a textbook is my most preferred source for this context) that deal with Jacobian of $\varphi$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't any book at hand, but [the usual argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Derivative_of_the_matrix_inverse) shows that the derivative of $X\mapsto X^{-1}$ is the linear map $H\mapsto-X^{-1}HX^{-1}$, meaning that the Jacobian matrix of $\varphi$ is $J=-(X^{-1})^T\otimes X^{-1}$. So, in your example, we should have
$$
\pmatrix{
\dfrac{d\varphi_1}{da}&\dfrac{d\varphi_1}{dc}&\dfrac{d\varphi_1}{db}&\dfrac{d\varphi_1}{dd}\\
\dfrac{d\varphi_2}{da}&\dfrac{d\varphi_2}{dc}&\dfrac{d\varphi_2}{db}&\dfrac{d\varphi_2}{dd}\\
\dfrac{d\varphi_3}{da}&\dfrac{d\varphi_3}{dc}&\dfrac{d\varphi_3}{db}&\dfrac{d\varphi_3}{dd}\\
\dfrac{d\varphi_4}{da}&\dfrac{d\varphi_4}{dc}&\dfrac{d\varphi_4}{db}&\dfrac{d\varphi_4}{dd}}
=\frac1{\det(X)^2}\pmatrix{-d^2&db&cd&-cb\\ dc&-da&-c^2&ca\\ bd&-b^2&-ad&ab\\ -bc&ba&ac&-a^2}.
$$

Comment: That is quite amazing actually. Just to clarify please, $J=-(X^{-1})^T\otimes X^{-1}$ or does $A$ mean something else here?

Comment: @yurnero Edited.